# Instantiate Hilt Worker for Instrumentation Testing?

Tags: android-testing, android-workmanager, android-instrumentation

I am having problem trying to initialize my `WorkerGetData` class for instrumentation testing. I have done the following:

1. removed the default work initializer in manifest file.
2. added configuration provider in the `Application` class.
3. called `WorkManagerTestInitHelper` in the Test file.
4. added `kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"` to app module.
5. added `kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42"` to app module.

But still get the error `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.myproject.WorkerGetData.<init> [class android.content.Context, class androidx.work.WorkerParameters]`.

I am using work manager version `2.7.1`.

## Code

```xml
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.startup.InitializationProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.androidx-startup"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:node="merge">
        <meta-data
            android:name="androidx.work.WorkManagerInitializer"
            android:value="androidx.startup"
            tools:node="remove" />
        </provider>
```

```kotlin
@HiltAndroidApp
class Application : android.app.Application(), Configuration.Provider {

    @Inject
    lateinit var workerFactory: HiltWorkerFactory

    override fun getWorkManagerConfiguration() =
        Configuration.Builder()
            .setWorkerFactory(workerFactory)
            .build()

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@HiltWorker
class WorkerGetData @AssistedInject constructor(
    val repository: MyRepository,
    @Assisted val context: Context,
    @Assisted workerParameters: WorkerParameters,
    ): CoroutineWorker(context, workerParameters) {

    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        val data = repository.getData()
        return Result.success(data)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun testGetDataWorker() {
        val request = OneTimeWorkRequestBuilder<WorkerGetData>()
            .build()
        
        val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
        workManager.enqueue(request).result.get() /*<-----------------------error here*/
        
        val workInfo = workManager.getWorkInfoById(request.id).get()
        assertThat(workInfo.state).isEqualTo(WorkInfo.State.SUCCEEDED)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a 6th item which I had forgot to do. I needed to create a `WorkerFatory()` so that `Hilt` could correctly inject `WorkerGetData` constructor. There is a great article from Pietro Maggi on how to do this:

https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/customizing-workmanager-with-dagger-1029688c0978